# Copy of existing wordpress site returns 302 in Docker Windows

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm a WP noob but have to fix some bugs on an existing wp site. I don't want to do that on the live environment, so I try to mirror it in docker (apache, php, mysql...all with similar versions like on the live environment).

- I copied all php from their ftp
- migrated the mysql data

When I access this local site I get a 302 redirect to the live site

At the beginning of wp-config.php I added

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:8180' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost:8180' );
```

But still the same.
Any ideas?

---

Here is the full wp-config.php as asked in the comments

```
<?php
/** changing the site url (https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) */
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:8180' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost:8180' );

define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED',true);
define('DB_NAME', 'replaced');
define('DB_USER', 'replaced');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'replaced');
define('DB_HOST', 'db:3306');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
define('AUTH_KEY',         'replaced');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'replaced');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'replaced');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'replaced');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'replaced');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'replaced');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'replaced');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'replaced');
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';
define('WPLANG', 'de_DE');
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )  define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
/* fixes safe_mode problems */
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/');
```

### Update

I followed the running code using xdebug. The redirect went to the live site because of the database entry (options table) '_transient_pll_languages_list'. It cached the url to the live site.
As it's called transient I simply removed it. Now I still have the redirect (now 301) but to my local site. So now I have a feedback loop.

I guess I will search and remove all 'transient' entries next.
**Is there a simpler way to remove all cached data from the db?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the problem was but after deactivating the SEO Plugin the problem went away. The site still worked after the SEO Plugin was activated again.
So it was some kind of plugin cache problem I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement myself to develop an existing WordPress site locally, so I made this repository: https://github.com/lumonald/existing-wordpress-development-docker

You can disable any caching plugins in the `.env` file, and it automatically finds/replaces the URL in the database for you.

It takes care of `wp-config.php` in the background for you, however if you need to edit this you can add it as a volume to the WordPress container within `docker-compose.yml`

Bare in mind this uses the latest version of WordPress, but this can be changed in the `docker-compose.yml` file, as can the MySQL version if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used docker, but according to me the following code is missing the folder name.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:8180' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost:8180' );
```

It should be something like

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:8180/foldername/' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost:8180/foldername/' );
```

Or else you can directly change the URL in the wp_options table, change the siteurl and home to your actual URL. Also, try clearing the cache folder or disable the cache plugin if it exists.

I hope this solves your issue.

Regards

Comment: Thx, which foldername do you mean? index.php is directly in /var/www/html of the apache container with the default vhost config, so I'd guess the site should be directly at /. 
I tried changing siteurl and home in the database but same as with the changes in wp-config...till redirecting to the live page

Comment: What we do while using xampp or wamp we create a folder in the route directory and then add our site files over there. You can try that same. Also please create a new htaccess file with default code you can get it from there https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: Please check the htaccess file as well as if there is any cache plugin then you will need to disable it.

Comment: Hmm, so you mean I could put the complete wordpress files into a folder and try localhost/folder. I guess as it redirects to the live page it gets the data from somewhere. So it seems to reach index.php. That's why I don't think that the problem is in the path.
.htaccess is unchanged

Comment: Added it above in the original post

Comment: Seems like the home_url for the current language is different as the one I set in the db and wp-config. Still have to find where it is set for the language but I'm getting closer